# TypeScript with styled-components

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components

TypeScript newbie here. I have a below component using `styled-components` that I would like to convert to `TypeScript`.

```
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import styled from 'styled-components'


const propTypes = {
  name: PropTypes.string.isRequired // https://material.io/tools/icons/?style=baseline
}

const Icon = styled(({name, className, ...props}) => <i className={`material-icons ${className}`} {...props}>{name}</i>)`
  font-size: ${props => props.theme.sizeLarger};
`

Icon.propTypes = propTypes

export default Icon
```

I know I can replace my `propTypes` with an `interface`

```
interface Props {
  name: string
}
```

However, TypeScript complains that I leave `className` undeclared. The thing is, I would ideally like to use the `interface` as a sort of spec for props that a developer can provide, without having to declare props like `className` or `theme` which are injected by libraries like `styled-components`.

How do I properly convert this component to TypeScript?

Answer (score 12):

```js
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";

interface Props {
  name: string;
  className?: string;
}

const NonStyledIcon: React.SFC<Props> = ({ name, className, ...props }) => (
  <i className={`material-icons ${className}`} {...props}>
    {name}
  </i>
);

const Icon = styled(NonStyledIcon)`
  font-size: ${props => props.theme.sizeLarger};
`;

export default Icon;
```

As per the styled-components [TypeScript docs](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/api#caveat-with-classname): when defining a component you will need to mark className as optional in your Props interface

Comment: Hm... declaring `className` feels both redundant and misleading though, doesn't it? This tells a potential user of the component that they may set a `className` prop, in which case the component wouldn't work as expected, right?

Comment: I'd say that's a valid objection, but it's still the official way of doing it

Comment: That's annoying. I think the interface should be augmented when you are augmenting the style.

Comment: Thank you - this answer is complete and helped me pretty much. Well done!

Answer (score 6):

Here's a comprehensive approach using Styled Components v5 with React Native that will work with plain React as well. If you're not using a theme you can skip to the `StyledProps` section at the bottom.

- Define your theme type.

  ```js
  // MyTheme.ts

  export type MyTheme = {
    colors: {
      primary: string;
      background: string;
    };
  };
  ```
- Use the type on your themes.

  ```js
  // themes.ts

  export const LightTheme: MyTheme = {
    colors: {
      primary: 'white',
      background: 'white',
    },
  };

  export const DarkTheme: MyTheme = {
    colors: {
      primary: 'grey',
      background: 'black',
    },
  };
  ```
- Use [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) to "merge" the MyTheme type into Styled Components default theme.

  ```js
  // styled.d.ts

  import 'styled-components';
  import { MyTheme } from '../src/themes/MyTheme';

  declare module 'styled-components' {
    // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-empty-interface
    export interface DefaultTheme extends MyTheme {}
  }
  ```

OK, cool. The `theme` prop is correctly typed.
What about the components themselves?

- Wrap your specific component props in the `StyledProps` type.

  ```js
  import { StyledProps } from 'styled-components';
  import styled from 'styled-components/native';

  type MyViewProps = StyledProps<{
    backgroundColor?: string;
    isAlert?: boolean;
  }>;

  const MyView = styled.View(
    (props: MyViewProps) => `
      background-color: ${props.backgroundColor || props.theme.colors.background};
      color: ${props.isAlert ? red : props.theme.colors.primary}
    `,
  );
  ```

In this example both `props.backgroundColor` and `props.theme.colors.background` will auto-complete. When you update `MyTheme` type or the specific component type it should just work.

[image: component auto-complete]

[image: them auto-complete]

Comment: It actually helps me a lot !! Thx

Comment: User beware: naming the file `styled-components.d.ts` causes it to completely override the @types definitions. Instead you should name it `styled.d.ts` or put the declaration alongside other global types inside `index.d.ts`

Answer (score 0):

There are many things happening here.

props.theme is not going to typed properlly unless you have the internal type for Theme augmented somewhere like this....

```
declare module "styled-components" {
    /* tslint:disable */
    export interface DefaultTheme extends YourThemeInterfaceType {}
}
```

This will change the type of props.theme to YourThemeInterfaceType, if you follow the augmentation documentation properlly but if you can't just create a styled-components.d.ts file and this to your tsconfig.

```
"include": [
    "src/**/*"
],
```

Next you need the type of the arguments to know "name" is a string, and className is also i'm assuming a optional string to do this just rewrite the above to this.

```
interface IIconProps {
    name: string;
    className?: string;
};

const Icon = styled(({name, className, ...props}: IIconProps) => <i className={`material-icons ${className}`} {...props}>{name}</i>)`
    font-size: ${props => props.theme.sizeLarger};
`;


const test = <Icon name={"xyz"} className={"xyz"}/> // passes typecheck.
```

Hope this helps.

EDIT: also proptypes are usless in typescript.