# Does using the `css` function inside a styled component cause a performance hit?

Tags: css, styled-components

To get proper **code completion, linting, and coloring** of styled-components code using Visual Studio Code we've been using the `css` function as a template wrapper.

Here's an example.  Notice the blue `css` functions.

`import styled, { css } from 'styled-components/native';`.

[image]

Without the `css` function all the css code is simply green text without any editor smarts.

Does this have a performance impact? 
Are we be better off foregoing the code editor conveniences and using simple template literals?

Comment: I've ran into the same issue and have been trying to solve it in a variety of ways that didn't work. Using `css` was not one of them. Thank you for enlightening me :) upvoted! Plus, I agree with the answer below. It might add some weight, but it would probably be insignificant in size.

Comment: @TalKoren Using `css` in combination with [this answer on how to type styled components](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60662122/25197) has pretty much solved all our vscode editor issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Style definitions from `styled-components` are parsed and extracted as plain CSS at build time into  tags in the head of your index.html file.

As a result, your html file may get larger, but for there to be a noticeable performance hit, you'd need an enormous amount of styles. At that point, you might just consider refactoring.

My two cents, if its working for you and the tool you chose doesn't introduce new bugs and/or performance issues that threaten your app's vitality, just stick with it until you see a need to change it.